# Pyspark: How to set the same id to all the rows that have the same value in another column?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset like this one:

```
  +----------+------------+
  |id        |event       |
  +----------+------------+
  | 1        |A           |
  | 2        |B           |
  | 3        |C           |
  | 4        |C           |
  | 5        |A           |
  | 6        |D           |
  | 7        |B           |
  +----------+------------+
```

And I would like either to modify id or add another column where all the equal values in column "event" have the same id. And I would like the rows to remain in the same order as they are now.

This is how I would like the data to look at the end (the value of "id" doesn't matter as long as it's unique for each event)

```
  +----------+------------+
  |id        |event       |
  +----------+------------+
  | 1        |A           |
  | 2        |B           |
  | 3        |C           |
  | 3        |C           |
  | 1        |A           |
  | 4        |D           |
  | 2        |B           |
  +----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE

Adding [monotonically_increasing_id()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html) to see your data in the original input after setting an id:

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
> unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the
> partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each
> partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame
> has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8
> billion records.

```py
output_df = (input_df
             .withColumn('order', f.monotonically_increasing_id())
             .withColumn('id', f.first('id').over(Window.partitionBy('event'))))
output_df.sort('order').show()

+---+-----+-----------+
| id|event|      order|
+---+-----+-----------+
|  1|    A| 8589934592|
|  2|    B|17179869184|
|  3|    C|25769803776|
|  3|    C|34359738368|
|  1|    A|42949672960|
|  6|    D|51539607552|
|  2|    B|60129542144|
+---+-----+-----------+
```

#### OLD

To "preserve" the dataframe order, create another column and keep `id` intact to sort whenever you want:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

input_df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, 'A'],
  [2, 'B'],
  [3, 'C'],
  [4, 'C'],
  [5, 'A'],
  [6, 'D'],
  [7, 'B']
], ['id', 'event'])

output_df = input_df.withColumn('group_id', f.first('id').over(Window.partitionBy('event')))
output_df.sort('id').show()

+---+-----+--------+
| id|event|group_id|
+---+-----+--------+
|  1|    A|       1|
|  2|    B|       2|
|  3|    C|       3|
|  4|    C|       3|
|  5|    A|       1|
|  6|    D|       6|
|  7|    B|       2|
+---+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you! And what if the id column is not sorted in order? Currently if I use row_number() for the id it messes up my data (probably because my data is too big I end up having a row from the beginning, then a row from the end, then another from the beginning when I use row_number() to generate the id and I would like to keep them in order). So I will probably have to use monotonicallyIncreasingId() instead

Comment: `Window` operator will shuffle your data in any case, so yes, `monotonically_increasing_id()` it's the answer to preserve your order

Comment: And monotonically_increasing_id() is increasing so I would still be able to use your solution, right?

Comment: Of course, I updated my answer to show how it should be implemented

Answer (score 0):

Just group your original dataframe by column `event` and aggregate like `max(col('id'))`, and you will get a new dataframe like:

```
  +----------+------------+
  |event     |maxid       |
  +----------+------------+
  | A        |5           |
  | B        |7           |
  | C        |4           |
  | D        |6           |
  +----------+------------+
```

The next step is to join this new dataframe with you original dataframe (on column event), and the column `maxid` is what you want.